# php form hide process page before moving on

Tags: php

I have a page that is calling another file to get MySQL data on load.
When I load the page, I call to a MySQL DB and get data allowing the user to enter a code that unlocks some features.

main-page.php
process-page.php

main-page.php has:

```
include('process-page.php');
```

near the top, then loads the HTML.

process-page.php connects to the MySQL DB, connects to my MongoDB, then runs 3 SQL queries and writes the results into my MongoDB collection.

Everything works fine, except MongoDB (so it's very fast) and I'm passing information into it from a MySQL DB (so it's very slow).

The problem is that I'm echoing the data in the preloading page so I see the data, then my page loads.
I know I can stop echoing the data, but MySQL is slow and I would get a white page until the data process is completed.

Is there a better method of loading my page and having the included page be hidden as it collects data?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for some kind of "please wait" or loading message to be displayed while the data is being fetched?

Comment: Kind of a strange thing to happen, but what you can do is have HTML already on the page and on that HTML page put something like `<?php echo $text; ?>` for where you want the content, other than this I don't really know what you are asking for...

Comment: load some "please wait" type HTML, flush it to the browser, and then put the include lower down from that. Then once the processing has finished, load some more HTML which includes a bit of javascript which will hide the "please wait" markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally just added a DIV with display:none style.

I was hoping for some AJAX type change I could make that would collect the data in the background.

Thanks for all your good answers.